# Ability to convert a json file to js in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, react-app-rewired

We are using create-react-app to build our declarative framework. In this framework, we author a json file which gets loaded into a react-component by webpack. We have authored specific loader for that. This works well in the browser. But facing issues with unit testing. Create-react-app uses Jest for unit testing.
What I want to acheive is transform these json files in js or react component, but hitting following limitations

1. If I add custom transform for json, then it does not work due to restriction put up by jest-runtime.
   Post transformation, it expects the output to be json only. See Jest-runtime code which restricts

[image]

2. If I rename file extensions to '.vm' then it never picks up my transformer as create-react-app add fileTransformer in following cases. The highlighted transformer gets picked up for all other types mentioned in that regex.

[image]

Need your guidance to resolve this issue.

Comment: The reason it expects the output to be json is because it makes mocking json files super simple

``data.json   and  __mock__/data.json``

https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/8278#issuecomment-496316634

Comment: Ideally your option 2 should work, if you override the transform object.

could you share your package.json's jest object (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#configuration)

Comment: Have you gone through this:
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2578

Answer (score 0):

Webpack Docs: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/json5-loader/
The Config for conversion of JSON to JS would look something like this. Then you could pass it into Jest rather than have Jest try to convert it during runtime.

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.json5$/i,
        loader: 'json5-loader',
        type: 'javascript/auto',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Or maybe have the custom loader here instead of the JSON5 one.